# Should Javascript Input to HTML form onSubmit with # action to PHP $_GET (all code on same file) work in theory?

Tags: php, javascript, html, calendar, onsubmit

I have the code request a date to be chosen by the user through this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var k3 = new Kalendae(document.getElementById("cal"), {
                months:3,
                format:'DD-MM-YYYY',
                mode:'single'
            });
        </script>
```

The user selects a date through the javascript and hits an html submit button:

```
    <form name="input_data" action="#" method="post" 
onSubmit="javascript:location.href="#?date_value=" + k3.getSelected();">
```

**This code's html action directs it to reload the same page with # so that php can capture it with:**

```
$dateValue= $_GET['date_value'];
```

If I echo $dateValue should it echo the original javascript input in theory?  If no, how would it need to be modified?

Comment: Not by mixing POST and GET like OP does, no.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

should work.

Say you call your button "Save" (name="save"). This will make trigger the PHP on submit.

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) { // Your stuff here
```

You should instead update your calandar information on change, storing it in a hidden input-field. I know submitting a form with a hash-tag is causing problems in several browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `#` from the form tag like so:

```
<form name="input_data" action="#" method="post" 
onSubmit="javascript:location.href="?date_value=" + k3.getSelected();">
```

The url will be appended `?date_value=Whatever` and called, but the form submits and grab the action and post the data to it and if you keep it the page won't be called, so theoretically no cause the get would be lost because of the second page load with not get value, but you can get this working by using this editing to your form like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit() {
        document.input_data.action = "?date_value="+k3.getSelected();
    }
</script>

<body>
    <form name="input_data" action="" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:edit();">
        ...
    </form>
</body>
```

And this will send the get value alongside the post values from the form and you can do it without the need to another function by updating the onSubmit attribute in the form and delete the edit function like so:

```
<body>
    <form name="input_data" action="" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:this.action='?date_value'+k3.getSelected();">
        ...
    </form>
</body>
```